# Not able to make first tab active for angular2 tab component

Tags: angular, typescript

```
I have tabs.component.ts file like 

 //Detail class for tab details
class Detail {
    title: string; // Name of the tab
    id: string //Id for the tab
    text: string; // Tab Content
    removable: boolean; // Variable to determine whether to display delete button next to tab
}

//Component to add and delete a tab
@Component({
    selector: 'de-tabs',
    template: require('./tabs.component.html'),
})
export class TabsComponent {    
    details: Detail[] = [];
    id: number = 1; //Tab id  

    constructor() {
        //Add Tab1 as default tab 
        this.details.push({
            title: `Calculation1`,
            id: '1',
            text: `Some detail text for ${this.id}...`,
            removable: false
        });
        //Add tab titled "+" as the last tab
        this.addNewTabOption();        
    }

    //Method to add a new tab
    addDetail() {
        //Remove the last tab titled "+"
        this.details.pop();
        //Iterate the id to point to next number
        this.id++;
        //Add the new tab details
        this.details.push({
            title: `Calculation${this.id}`,
            id: `${this.id}`,
            text: `Some detail text for ${this.id}...`,
            removable: true
        });
        //Add tab titled "+" as the last tab
        this.addNewTabOption();        
    }

    //Adding tab titled "+" as the last tab
    //Make removable variable as false since we don't want to display delete button for "+" tab
    addNewTabOption() {
        this.details.push({
            title: `+`,
            id: '+',
            text: ``,
            removable: false
        });
    }   
} and html like 

<!--Calling tab component to add and remove a tab-->
<de-tab>
    <!--Add Extra Channel section-->   
    <template *ngFor="let detail of details" de-pane [title]="detail.title" [id]="detail.id">       

            </div>
</template>
</de-tab>  


My tab component and html are as follows.

//Directive to set the active attribute for the tab
@Directive({
    selector: '[de-pane]'
})
export class UiPane {
    @Input() title: string;
    @Input() id: string;
    @Input() removable: string;
    private _active: boolean = false;


    constructor(public viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
        public templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) { }

    //Set the active tab and embed the tab pane template in the view container
    //If not active remove it from the view container
    @Input() set active(active: boolean) {
        if (active == this._active) return;
        this._active = active;
        if (active) {
            this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        } else {
            this.viewContainer.remove(0);
        }
    }

    //Get the active attribute for a tab
    get active(): boolean {
        return this._active;
    }
}

//Component to create and delete a tab
@Component({
    selector: 'de-tab',
    template: require('./tab.component.html'),
    styles: ['a { cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; }']
})

export class TabComponent implements OnInit {
    @ContentChildren(UiPane) panes: QueryList<UiPane>; //Get the list of tab panes

    select(pane: UiPane) {
        if (pane.title == '+') {
            this.panes.toArray().forEach((p: UiPane) => p.active = p == pane);
        } else {
            this.panes.toArray().forEach((p: UiPane) => p.active = p == pane);
        }       
    }


}


HTML is 

<!--Display the tabs with small delete button for each tab-->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li *ngFor="let pane of panes"
        (click)="select(pane)"
        role="presentation" [class.active]="pane.active">
        <a>{{pane.title}}
            <span [hidden]="!pane.removable">
                <span (click)="removeTab(pane);" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>    
</ul>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

I want to know how to make the first tab to display the content on page load. I tried using ngAfterContentInit method and pass the first pane to the select method but it did not seem working. Can you please let me know how to make first pane active and load the details of the tab.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar but not using tabs, I used panels, but the concept might be the same. here is what I did.

Here is my HTML file

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-heading bg-gray-lighter text-bold">Settings</div>
            <div class="list-group">
                <a class="list-group-item" (click)="settingActive=1" [ngClass]="{'active': (settingActive == 1)}">Tab Title 1</a>
                <a class="list-group-item" (click)="settingActive=2" [ngClass]="{'active': (settingActive == 2)}">Tab Title 2</a>
                <a class="list-group-item" (click)="settingActive=3" [ngClass]="{'active': (settingActive == 3)}">Tab Title 3</a>
                <a class="list-group-item" (click)="settingActive=4" [ngClass]="{'active': (settingActive == 4)}">Tab Title 4</a>
                <a class="list-group-item" (click)="settingActive=5" [ngClass]="{'active': (settingActive == 5)}">Tab Title 5</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div *ngIf="settingActive == 1">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading text-bold"> Panel Title 1</div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                  <!-- content here -->

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="settingActive == 2">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading text-bold"> Panel Title 2</div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                  <!-- content here -->     

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="settingActive == 3">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading text-bold"> Panel Title 3</div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                 <!-- content here -->  

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="settingActive == 4">
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-heading text-bold"> Panel Title 4</div>
              <div class="panel-body">

               <!-- content here -->  

              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="settingActive == 5">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading text-bold">Panel Title 5 </div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <!-- content here -->  


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in my Class I added this so it implements on init. What this does is sets which tab you want to be active first on load.

```
export class BusinessInfoComponent implements OnInit {
  settingActive = 1;
}
```

I hope this can help you in some way :)